# Find indexOf character after certain index

Tags: javascript, regex

Pretty basic but I'm afraid I'm overlooking a simple solution. I have the following string `...   IBAN: NL56INGB06716xxxxx   ...`

I need the accountnumber so I'm looking for `indexOf("IBAN: ")` but now I need to find the next space/whitespace char after that index.

I don't really think I would need a loop for this but it's the best I can come up with. Regex capture group maybe better? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can pass a starting index as Paul suggested, it would seem that a simple regex may just be easier.

```
var re = /IBAN:\s*(\S+)/
```

The capture group will hold the sequence of non-whitespace characters after the `IBAN:`

```
var match = re.exec(my_str)
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: `\W+` should be enough for IBANs

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I wasn't sure which characters should be included, so I just went with his target space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) `String.prototype.indexOf`

> `str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`
>
> `fromIndex`
> *Optional.* The location within the calling string to start the search from. It can be any integer. The default value is `0`.

n.b. `.indexOf` will only look for a specific substring, if you want to find a choice from many characters, you will either need to loop and compare or use *RegExp*

---

Gracious example

```
var haystack = 'foo_ _IBAN: Bar _ _';
var needle = 'IBAN: ',
    i = haystack.indexOf(needle),
    j;
if (i === -1) {
    // no match, do something special
    console.warn('One cannot simply find a needle in a haystack');
}
j = haystack.indexOf(' ', i + needle.length);
// now we have both matches, we can do something fancy
if (j === -1) {
    j = haystack.length; // no match, set to end?
}
haystack.slice(i + needle.length, j); // "Bar"
```

Comment: Paul - I believe your answer is the correct one, most suitable for the question title: *Find indexOf character after certain index*...  But, out of courtesy, you could complete your answer with the result code: `indexOf(" ", indexOf("IBAN: "))`

Comment: @LcSalazar: One problem is that the question states that he wants the next *"space/whitespace"*, so it seems like more than just a space should be included since whitespace can mean one of multiple characters. The `.indexOf()` could still be used, and is still correct, but it would need to be done in a loop over all possibilities.

Comment: @LcSalazar Doing my best to please you!

Comment: @sixfingeredman Think it's always spaces looking at the data. Too bad ABN Bank only provides one CSV format and that has the account-number in the comment column -.-